# Plotting the "Average " curve of set of curves

Tags: r, matlab

I have a collection of n curves, that is, the points (x,y) for each of these n curves. I am trying to plot a "resultant curve" or average curve. Ie, take the average value of 'n' y coords for each x and plot the result. The problem is the xs are not the same for the n curves. I know I probably have to interpolate or something, but I couldn't find a routine to do it online. Does anyone know of an r package or a Matlab code or C or C++ code for this implemented by someone ? If not, any ideas how to go about the interpolation in a clever way ? Thanks!!

Comment: For linear interpolation, you can use `approx`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

An R solution using `approx` for linear interpolation.

First I create some data ( you question mis a reproducible example).
Here I am creating a list , with 5 data.frame, with differents xs:

```
ll <- lapply(1:5,function(i)
  data.frame(x=seq(i,length.out=10,by=i),y=rnorm(10)))
```

Then to apply `approx`, I create a big data.frame containing all the data:

```
big.df <- do.call(rbind,ll)
```

Then , I plot the linear approximation and all my series :

```
plot(approx(big.df$x,big.df$y),type='l')
lapply(seq_along(ll), 
       function(i) points(ll[[i]]$x,ll[[i]]$y,col=i))
```

[image]

Comment: Thanks!! Does exactly what I wanted it to do.

Comment: is there a way to use the approx approach in ggplot? - Not sure if I need to open a new question to ask this. Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

If you are using the `curve` function in R, you can assign the values of the curve to a list (with <-). This allows you to average your curves afterwards.

```
x <-runif(10)                               
plot(x, ylim=c(-5,5))                       
a <-curve(sin, add=TRUE, col="red")         
b <-curve(cos, add=TRUE, col="blue")        
xx <-(a$x+b$x)/2 # x average                              
yy <-(a$y+b$y)/2 # y average                                  
lines(xx,yy, col="purple")  #draw average curve
```

[image]

Answer (score 1):

A Matlab solution using [`interp1`](http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/interp1.html):

```
% X and Y data for two curves
x1 = -1:0.11:1;
x2 = -1:0.09:1;
y1 = x1.^2;
y2 = x2.^2;

% Assemble variable length (ragged) data into cell arrays
X = {x1;x2};
Y = {y1;y2};

% Vector of interpolated x coordinates
Xq = -1:0.1:1;

% Interpolate each curve  to Xq and save in row of matrix Yq
N = length(X);
Yq(N,length(Xq)) = 0;
for i = 1:N
    Yq(i,:) = interp1(X{i},Y{i},Xq);
end

% Display result
figure;
plot(Xq,Yq,'.-')
```

You might play with the various interpolation methods available in `interp1`. If you have R2012a or newer, note that he `interp1` function [will be changing a bit in the future](http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/release-notes.html#bta5yau).