# Plotting the “Average ” curve of set of curves in ggplot2

Tags: r, ggplot2

My Question is exactly this one:

[Plotting the "Average " curve of set of curves](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16763967/plotting-the-average-curve-of-set-of-curves?answertab=active#tab-top)

but I am looking to implement the accepted answer (below) in ggplot. is it possible?

First I create some data. Here I am creating a list , with 5 data.frame, with differents xs:

```
 ll <- lapply(1:5,function(i)
  data.frame(x=seq(i,length.out=10,by=i),y=rnorm(10)))
```

Then to apply approx, I create a big data.frame containing all the data:

```
big.df <- do.call(rbind,ll)
```

Then , I plot the linear approximation and all my series :

```
plot(approx(big.df$x,big.df$y),type='l')
lapply(seq_along(ll), 
       function(i) points(ll[[i]]$x,ll[[i]]$y,col=i))
```

***EDIT***

structure of my data (example. the actual DF contain 183000 rows)

```
structure(list(timeseries = c(1, 7, 59, 0, 0, 5, 0, 0, 1, 0), 
t = c(1, 3, 7, 1, 3, 7, 1, 3, 7, 1)), .Names = c("timeseries",
```

"t"), row.names = c(NA, 10L), class = "data.frame")

Answer (score 6, accepted):

In the code below, we start with the list you created (depending on what your actual data looks like, there are probably better approaches, but I've left it as is for now). Then we use `bind_rows` to convert it to a single data frame and `mutate` to add the interpolated values. The we feed it to ggplot on the fly. `geom_line` plots the interpolated values.

The interpolated points are the exact average of all y values at each x value in the data. For comparison, I've also added `geom_smooth`, which uses locally weighted regression to plot a smooth curve through the data. The `span` argument in `geom_smooth` can be used to determine the amount of smoothing.

```
library(tidyverse)
theme_set(theme_classic())

# Fake data
set.seed(2)
ll <- lapply(1:5,function(i)
  data.frame(x=seq(i,length.out=10,by=i),y=rnorm(10)))

# Combine into single data frame and add interpolation column
bind_rows(ll, .id="source") %>% 
  mutate(avg = approx(x,y,xout=x)$y) %>% 
  ggplot(aes(x, y)) +
    geom_point(aes(colour=source)) +
    geom_line(aes(y=avg)) +
    geom_smooth(se=FALSE, colour="red", span=0.3, linetype="11")
```

[image]

Now let's go through the individual data processing steps:

1. Generate a single data frame from the list:

   ```
   dat = bind_rows(ll, .id="source")
   ```

   Here are selected rows from that data frame:

   ```
   dat[c(1:3, 15:17, 25:27), ]

      source  x            y
   1       1  1 -0.896914547
   2       1  2  0.184849185
   3       1  3  1.587845331
   15      2 10  1.782228960
   16      2 12 -2.311069085
   17      2 14  0.878604581
   25      3 15  0.004937777
   26      3 18 -2.451706388
   27      3 21  0.477237303
   ```
2. We can get interpolated values as follows:

   ```
    with(dat, approx(x, y, xout=x))
   ```

   To get just the y values, which is all we wanted above, we would do:

   ```
    with(dat, approx(x, y, xout=x))$y
   ```

   To add the y-values to the data frame:

   ```
    dat$avg = with(dat, approx(x, y, xout=x))
   ```

To create the plot, we performed the data processing steps using functions from the `dplyr` package, which is part of the `tidyverse` suite of packages the we loaded at the start of the code. It includes the pipe (`%>%`) operator, which allows us to chain functions one after the other and feed the data directly into `ggplot` without having to assign the intermediate data frame to an object (although we *can* of course create the intermediate data frame first if we wish). For example:

```
dat = bind_rows(ll, .id="source") %>% 
  mutate(avg = approx(x,y,xout=x)$y)

ggplot(dat, aes(x, y)) +
  geom_point(aes(colour=source)) +
  geom_line(aes(y=avg)) +
  geom_smooth(se=FALSE, colour="red", span=0.3, linetype="11")
```

Comment: This is a super detailed answer. thanks a lot for taking the time to produce it.

I have a problem though. I have a dataframe of the following form:


  timeseries t
1          1 1
2          7 3
3         59 7
4          0 1
5          0 3
6          5 7

two columns t (time, xaxis) and timeseries (yaxis) This dataframe has 183000 rows.

If I try to follow your steps

`a%>%mutate(average=approx(t,timeseries,xout = t)$timeseries)`

I get the following error: _Error in mutate_impl(.data, dots) : 
  Column `average` is of unsupported type NULL_

Comment: It should be `approx(t,timeseries,xout = t)$y`. The list element returned by `approx` is called `y`, regardless of the names in the input data frame. Run `approx` on a small sample of your data and look at the output so you can get a better idea of how the output of `approx` is structured.

Comment: For example, try `x=1:10; z=rnorm(10); approx(x, z, xout=x)`.